# Sorting Firestore Documents

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any possible way I can order the Cloud Firestore documents of a collection based on a number at a value of a specific field. For example in the collection `ids` there are documents and in each one there is a field called `idNumber`. The value of that idNumber is 0 then in the next document is 1 then 2 etc. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes it is! To order the documents within a collection by a specific numeric property, please use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference idsRef = rootRef.collection("ids");
Query query = idsRef.orderBy("idNumber", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

This query will order your documents according to the `idNumber` property ascending. If you want a reverse order just change the direction to `DESCENDING`. That's it!

**Edit:**

According to the official documentation of Query's [orderBy(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#orderBy(java.lang.String)) method:

> Creates and returns a new Query that's additionally sorted by the specified field.

And according to Query's [orderBy(String field, Query.Direction direction)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#orderBy(java.lang.String,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.Direction)) method:

> Creates and returns a new Query that's additionally sorted by the specified field, optionally in descending order instead of ascending.

Comment: So, it is sorted by default by ascending or descending numbers? So does that mean if I put string value it will sort it alphabetically? Thanks

Comment: Yes, in ascending order but please see my updated answer. In case of strings, yes, it will order `alphabetically`.

Comment: In case anyone else is here, on Node, and is tearing their hair out trying to figure out how to static import `Query.Direction` for ordering directions, don't bother - there's an overload of `orderBy` which allows you to just supply `'desc'` or `'asc'` strings as the second param.

Comment: @bsplosion If you supply 'desc' or 'asc' strings as the second param, doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: On Node it behaves exactly as expected: `'desc'` sorts in descending order and `'asc'` sorts in ascending order.  I tried to clearly caveat that this is only applicable to Node (not necessarily Java, sadly).  On Node, those strings are just enums of their `Query.Direction` variants.

Answer (score 0):

You can order the fields of a collection like this:

```
CollectionReference idsRef = db.collection("ids");
idsRef.orderBy("idNumber");
```

For further reading see: [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Comment: But I want the documents to be sorted, and to be based from numbers and not when they got created. For example the idNumber with 0 should be the first and then 1 then 2 then 3 ...