# Sort Firestore documents by a user defined hierarchy?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore db and it has some documents including a field for "position".
This "position" field can take values "senior lecturer", "Head of department", "Lecturer".
I want to sort this collection such that, the documents containing "Head of department" as the position should come to the top, the documents containing "senior lecturer" as the position should come next and the documents containing "lecturer" as the position should come to the bottom.

I can't just sort this alphabetically. ("H", "S" ,"L")

How do I do this in Firestore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Firestore Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538017/sorting-firestore-documents)

Comment: I can't just sort this alphabetically. I have my own hierarchy .

Comment: This should be addressed ***some** documents including*... So some documents have that field and some do not... What do you want to do with the ones that do not have the field at all?

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to create an extra field dedicated to your specific sorting, that you would call, for example, `positionSorting`.

In the NoSQL databases world, you should not hesitate to add new fields in order to simplify your queries (or to make them possible).

So for example this field would have a value of `1` if you save a doc with `Head of department` as the position value, `2` if it is a `Senior lecturer`, etc.

Then you just query your collection as follows:

```
users.orderBy("positionSorting").get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
     querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

If Renaud's approach (adding an explicit field with the sort-order) doesn't work for your use-case, I'd typically prefix the existing `position` field values with the sort order. So that they become:

```
"1 - Head of department"
"2 - Senior Lecturer"
"3 - Lecturer"
```

That way you *can* just sort on the `position` field and get them in the right order. If you don't want to show these numeric prefixes to the user, you can then hide them in your UI code.

**EDIT By Jay**

The only potential issue in the above is if more positions were added, for example the position *10 - Assistant's Assistant* will sort after *1 - head of department*. This is NOT an issue if you only have 10 position levels (0-9)

You could fix that by padding the positions so they all have the same number of digits;

```
001 - Head of Dept
002 - Senior Lecturer
.
.
.
010 - Assistant's Assistant
```

Comment: Tossed in a little edit that may help for future Firestore structure planning.

Comment: Hey Jay. Thanks for that. Note that this should typically be a comment, not an edit. ;-)

Comment: Feel free to delete what I added as I thought it would improve the answer and would be hard to read as a comment.